# Unable to install rgdal package

Tags: r, rstudio, shapefile, rgdal

I have to work with shapefiles and to convert these to rasters the package `rgdal` is recommended, however the package is not recognized (R v2.11, RStudio 0.98.501, Mac OS X 10_7_5). How could I still install `rgdal` or omit this package?

To clarify my question more, the error messages are:

```
> install.packages("rgdal")
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/macosx/leopard/contrib/2.11
Warning in install.packages :
  argument 'lib' is missing: using '/Users/myname/Library/R/2.11/library'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/macosx/leopard/contrib/2.11
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘rgdal’ is not available
```

Comment: run **setRepositories(graphics = getOption("menu.graphics"),
                ind = NULL, addURLs = character())** and select all repositories. try to install again.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the reply. I tried running this script but do not know how to select all repositories and R returns this message. Does someone knows what I am doing wrong?: > setRepositories(graphics = getOption("menu.graphics"), ind = NULL, addURLs = character())
Error in setRepositories(graphics = getOption("menu.graphics"), ind = NULL,  : 
  unused argument(s) (addURLs = character())

Comment: Are you stuck with 2.11 or could you update R?